# Instagram's video sharing Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

Following [Instagram's video sharing Android Intent](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/#sharing-a-video). Trivial edit to bypass a chooser and launch Instagram directly. [See Gist](https://gist.github.com/es0329/b41089ed3994b903b2711b7c8b43588a) of relevant code and adb output.

Kit Kat device works as intended, however Nougat device falls to Line#20, launching Play Store, as if Instagram isn't installed.

On both devices Line#14 of ShareDialog's startInstagram() does present a chooser of video-sharing capable apps, including Instagram.

Related code for sharing an image with this same approach works as intended on both devices.

**UPDATE 1**: Implementing the new ContentProvider approach makes Instagram crash upon launching the share Intent. I'll test sharing video to another social network to see if that works.

**UPDATE 2**: Turns out Instagram doesn't play nice with

`share.setDataAndType(contentUri, "video/*");`.

Setting them seperately, put everything in working order.

`share.setType("video/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);`

Comment: When you looked at the `Exception` that you got on Android 7.0, what did you learn?

Comment: `E/ShareDialog: e.getLocalizedMessage >> file:///storage/emulated/0/870_90.mp4 exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
E/ShareDialog: e.getCause >> null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging the exception on your gist on Android Nougat reveals the problem:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.mp4 exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

On Android Nougat you will need to use a provider:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.your.package.fileProvider", newFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
}
```

See: [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38200282/1048340)

Answer (score 1):

That would appear to be a `FileUriExposedException`. If your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, you cannot use `Uri.fromFile()` or other `file` `Uri` values in an `Intent` or other places (e.g., `setSound()` on a `Notification).

Use `FileProvider` to serve your file via a `ContentProvider`.